# You say that - meaning

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

I've come across this conversation exchange in the transcript of a textbook:

> (the speakers are discussing that a friend of theirs has been dismissed because he was sending personal emails from the company's computer)
>
> *Laura*: That's a bit unfair, isn't it?
>
> *Dom*: **You say that**, but actually what happened to him was he visited ...

I think I can guess what the meaning of "you say that" is: "you say that because you don't know the whole truth", but I'd never heard that phrase. I'm looking it up in different dictionaries but I can't find it.

Is it an usual phrase to indicate that somebody's guess is wrong?

Comment: What textbook is that? It doesn't sound idiomatic to me.

Comment: Outcomes - Intermediate

Answer (score 4):

Yes - *You say that, **but** [some refutation or caveat]* is idiomatically commonplace for many native speakers, in response to an assertion they disagree with.

It's nearly always used in a context where although the speaker doesn't *fully* agree with the preceding assertion, he recognizes that there's *some* truth in it.

In fact, you'll often hear *You **could** say that, but...*, which more explicitly acknowledges that the assertion is at least "credible", even if it's not completely accurate. Note that in this usage, ***you = one, anybody***, not necessarily the person being addressed (i.e. - what it amounts to is something like *It wouldn't be ridiculous for you/someone to say that, **but it's not entirely true***).

---

Also note that if the personal pronoun is stressed *(**You** say that, but...)*, the implied meaning shifts significantly. This form almost always occurs in contexts where the speaker *completely* disagrees; he intends to dismiss your opinion on the grounds that you're ignorant or biased, and/or to cite other sources more authoritative than you to refute what you said.

Comment: Can we think of "you say that" as a present subjunctive expression? Because a modal verb seems to be implied between "you and say", I think we can.

Comment: @Floret: You could say that, buy I think you're mistaken. So far as I'm concerned, it's normally just plain old Present Simple / Present Indicative. Not that I care much about such terminological details, but I suppose *We recommend **that he say that*** is a true "subjunctive" form (most people today would inflect the verb to *...he **says** that* anyway though). Have a look at [this](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/english-subjunctive-what-is-it/) for more background on the subjunctive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find the  example  to be idiomatic.

You  need either  a modal verb ('You can/could/will/would/might  that...'), and this would express hedged or partial  agreement with the other person; or you need to change what Dom says after 'You say that, but...'

*You say that, but...* is said to contradict what the other person has just said. So an idiomatic usage would be

-You say that, but actually it was fair. (And here's why. What actually  happened...)

Examples from Google Books:

> "Look, I've got to get going. I'm due in a meeting in about twenty minutes. We'll talk tonight."
>
> -"You say that,  but we won't. We won't talk. We don't know how to talk anymore."

([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=_FbqR7d3OWQC&pg=PA160&dq="You+say+that,+but"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIn-yN_dnNAhVi9YMKHaCEBM04HhDoAQg3MAU#v=onepage&q=%22You%20say%20that%2C%20but%22&f=false))

> ...He had to smile. Even [though she was] on maternity leave she was first and foremost a nurse. "I'll be fine, honey."
>
> -" You say that, but half the time you don't know how to put a Band-Aid on correctly."

([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=hAbalW1dz-kC&pg=PA64&dq="You+say+that,+but"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM3cKd_tnNAhVk0oMKHYveA6s4KBDoAQglMAI#v=onepage&q=%22You%20say%20that%2C%20but%22&f=false))

> "That's as may be. But I will never take a husband."
>
> -"You say that but you will,you will marry some great king or prince and break my heart."

([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=ryr3BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA74&dq="You+say+that,+but"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiujOb3_9nNAhWl5oMKHYFxBBgQ6AEIOTAF#v=onepage&q=%22You%20say%20that%2C%20but%22&f=false))

> 'But you're starting a new life, aren't you?  A place where there's no place  for me?'
>
> -'You say that, but it isn't true.

([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=bTapBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT90&dq="You+say+that,+but"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv0vyLhNrNAhVE9YMKHThqDFY4ChDoAQg9MAY#v=onepage&q=%22You%20say%20that%2C%20but%22&f=false))

This is the meaning of *You say that, but...*